# How to use NamedJdbcTemplate with Postgres regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, postgresql, java-8, spring-jdbc

I'm using Postgres:9.5.5 and Spring-Jdbc:4.3.7.

My select in postgres looks like this:

```
select id, birth_date, fullname from some_table where fullname ~ '\mSTACK\M'
```

Which will return true if fullname contains a word "STACK".

I have a problem with generating this query in Java (8) using NamedJdbcTemplate:

```
String sql = "select id, fullname, birth_date from some_table where fullname ~ '\m:name\M' and birth_date = :birth_date";

SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
    .addValue("name", "STACK")
    .addValue("birth_date", "22.07.2002");

namedJdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, ....);
```

The resulting SQL generated by JDBC:

```
SELECT id, fullname, birth_date FROM some_table WHERE fullname ~ '\m:name\M' AND birth_date = ?;
```

As you can see there is no trouble with birth_date param,
but JDBC didn't put "?" character instead of parameter ":name".

How can I explain to JDBC that my parameter ":name" is surrounded by regular expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'\m:name\M'` This result is logic, because you use your regex and the param between two quotes, instead.

You can use `||` to concatenate your regular expression with the word, like this :

```
fullname ~ ('\m' || :name || '\M')
```

If `:name` param equals to `STOCK` This will produce something like this :

```
fullname ~ '\mSTOCK\M'
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the answer!
That almost worked, I believe you need also brackets:
fullname ~ ('\m' || :name || '\M').

Comment: You are welcome @EgorStepanov Yes this is correct I forgot the parenthesis :)